# Pandas - Extracting all text after the 4th character

Tags: pandas

I am trying to see how can we extract all characters in a column after the 4th character.

```
col_a
XYZ123
ABCD001
```

Expecting the below

```
col_a, new_col
XYZ123, 23
ABCD001, D001
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with string slicing:

```
df['new_col']=df['col_a'].str[4:]
```

**OR**

Via re module:

```
import re
df['new_col']=df['col_a'].apply(lambda x:re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function of Pandas. Simple explanation would be, using regex `^.{4}(.*)$` by which getting everything apart from 1st 4 characters into capturing group and saving it to new column.

```
df['new_col'] = df['col_a'].str.extract(r'^.{4}(.*)$',expand=False)
```

Output of df will be as follows:

```
     col_a new_col
0   XYZ123      23
1  ABCD001     001
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

Extract alphanumerics left of the first 3 alphanumerics

```
df['new_col']= df.col_a.str.extract('((?<=^\w{3})\w+)')
```